# Complicated variable assignment in C (decompiled ELF)

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, reverse, elf

So I have to get password which "hides" somewhere here

```
void __regparm3 entry(undefined4 param_1,void *param_2,size_t param_3,void *param_4,size_t param_5)

{
  char cVar1;
  int iVar2;
  size_t __n;
  void *__buf;
  int unaff_retaddr;
  
  _write((int)prompt,param_2,param_3);
  _read(unaff_retaddr,param_4,param_5);
  iVar2 = 0;
  do {
    cVar1 = (**(code **)(&vfunc + (uint)(byte)(&vmp)[iVar2] * 4))(); //cant understand this
    if (cVar1 != (&vmr)[__n]) {
      _write((int)fail,__buf,__n);
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
      _exit(unaff_retaddr);
    }
    iVar2 = __n + 1;
  } while (iVar2 != 0x17);
  _write((int)success,__buf,0x17);
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
  _exit(unaff_retaddr);
}
```

I found that vmr contains 0x17 values and vmp only one: 03.

**Question:**

How cVar1 is created and especially what does mean this `(**(code **)(&vfunc + (uint)(byte)(&vmp)[iVar2] * 4))()`? Is this line converting vmp value to some number or what else?

Comment: Honestly, before you even *attempt* reverse engineering you should have a pretty solid basis in C, memory models and probably also some assembly knowledge.

Comment: What is your question? Why are you writing here?

Comment: Is this an autogenerated source code, something you did manually, or a combination? There's a lot of uncertainty in it. `__n` is never initialized, and it looks like it and `iVar2` should be united into one variable.

Comment: This is decompiled with Ghidra code of function from executable. I didnt write it.

Comment: I want to understand how cVar1 is created and especially what does mean this ```(**(code **)(&vfunc + (uint)(byte)(&vmp)[iVar2] * 4))() ```. This line converting vmp value to some number or what else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a call to a function referenced by an *indexed* function pointer returning something that is then stored into a `char` variable but:

- It seems to be obfuscated on purpose ;
- Some of the variables implied in this expression are visibly declared outside the sample of code we see here.

But anyway, the expression here says that:

1. `vfunc` is probably an array of 32-bits integers acting like pointers towards different callback functions, without being explicitly declared as pointers (probably because of some length & format purposes) ;
2. `vmp` is probably an array contains the number of the function to be called for each particular case ;
3. `&vmp` returns the address of this array (which is useless if this is really an array, can be necessary if it's an `union` or something) ;
4. `&vmp[iVar]` gets the value of entry indexed by `iVar` ;
5. `(uint)(byte)` then casts this value to a byte first (probably for trimming unnecessary bits) then to an integer. Remark that cast operator precedence `(…)` comes after the indexing one `[…]` ;
6. This index is multiplied by `* 4` because of 32-bits pointers, which tends to say that `vfunc` does not point at natively declared pointers, otherwise the pointer arithmetic would have applied ;
7. The so-obtained pointer is casted to `(code **)`, which is a "pointer to a pointer to some code". `code` here is probably an alias to a function pointer declared somewhere with `typedef` ;
8. This pointer is de-referenced twice to access the function itself: `(** …)`
9. This function is called (with no arguments) by appending the final parenthesis `…()` ;
10. This result of this function is assigned to cVar1 : `cVar1 = …`

Comment: This is autogenerated code so the types basically need to be all manually adjusted so that they’ll some meaning to the human as well as they do to the machine :)

Comment: Indeed. I noticed this point while reading the comments a second time after having posted. Thanks to highlight it.